# Making mirror texture in v-python/wx-python

Tags: python-3.x, wxpython, vpython

I'm trying to visualize a room in my project using vpython and I have searched a lot but I could not find a solution to implement mirror(via texture or other tricks) in wxpython/vpython
may someone help me?

Comment: What do mean by a mirror? Please provide more details what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: exactly a mirror which in my case it is placed in a room.